# How do I update the query parameter based on which component I am in?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I pass parameters to my link and I can access it from my parent component with `this.props.location`, but I also render other components in that parent component, and when I try to do `this.props.location` in my child component, it does not recognize what `this.props.location` is. What I am trying to figure out is 1. How would I access the query parameters in my child components, and 2. How would I update my query parameters based on which component I am in. i.e. link = www.example.com/profile?name="Jane Doe"&age="21" and I have 2 child components, name and age and when I update name to say Bob the route should update to www.example.com/profile?name="Bob"&age="21" and same for age.

pushing new route:

```
browserHistory.push({
  pathname: '/me',
  query: {name: "Jane Doe", age: "21"}
});
```

Parent component (me.jsx)

```
export default class Me extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.location.query); //prints my query parameters
    return (
       <div>
         <Name />
         <Age />         
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Name.jsx

```
export default class Name extends Component {
      render() {
        console.log(this.props.location.query); //error
        return (
           <div>
             <form>
               field to update name, need to change url query param "Name" to reflect the change
             </form>     
           </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the props to the child,

This will pass all the props from the parent to the child,

```
export default class Me extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.location.query); //prints my query parameters
    return (
       <div>
         <Name {...this.props} />
         <Age {...this.props} />         
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can also selectively pass props,

```
export default class Me extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.location.query); //prints my query parameters
    return (
       <div>
         <Name location={this.props.location} />
         <Age />         
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your two queries:

1. `this.props.location` is only accessible in your parent component as only that component receives it as props from Router. If you want to access them in your child component you need to explicitly pass it to them

Parent component (me.jsx)

```
export default class Me extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.location.query); 
    return (
      <div>
        <Name query={this.props.location.query} />
        <Age />         
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Name.jsx

```
export default class Name extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.query);
    return (
       <div>
         <form>

         </form>     
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2. In order to update the URL on change of form field, you need to push new route with updated value.

Name.jsx

```
export default class Name extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateNameInUrl = this.updateNameInUrl.bind(this);
  }

  updateNameInUrl (event) {
    let newName = event.target.value;
    browserHistory.push("/me", {name: newName, age: this.props.query.age};
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.query);
    return (
       <div>
         <form>
           <input type="text" value={this.props.query.name} onChange={this.updateNameInUrl} />
         </form>     
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```